# using radio buttons with javascript... getting null error

Tags: javascript

What I am trying do is, have 4 radio buttons that depict a math operation (add, subtract...) then based off of which one is checked, I will take the user entered numbers and perform the calculation. To do this i used an if else statement, so that it runs through the buttons and if it is checked it will perform the math operation. the problem I'm getting is a null error.

*document.getElementById(...) is null...if(document.getElementById('add').checked)*

I get this same error no matter which radio button is selected.
another issue I have is multiple radio buttons can be selected at once.

how can i code this so that only one button can be selected, and then depending on which button is checked perform that operation? why am I getting the null error?

I was under the impression that if the radio button was selected then document.getElementById('add').checked would return true other wise it would return as false moving to the next statment.

**HTML**

```
    <form>
        Enter two numbers, select a math, click the button to see result.
        Enter first number: <input type='number' id='num1'>
        Enter second number: <input type='number' id='num2'>    
        <h5>Select a math</h5>
        <input type='radio' name='add'>Add<br>
        <input type='radio' name='sub'>Subtract<br>
        <input type='radio' name='multi'>Multiply<br>
        <input type='radio' name='divis'>Division<br>
        <br>
        <button type='button' onclick='calculate();'>Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <p id='result'></p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function calculate(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    var res = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;

    if(document.getElementById('add').checked){
        res = num1 + num2;
    }else if(document.getElementById('sub').checked){
        res = num1 - num2;
    }else if(document.getElementById('multi').checked){
        res = num1 * num2;
    }else if(document.getElementById('divis').checked){
        if(num2 == 0){
            alert('Can not divide by ZERO!!');
        }else{
            res = num1 / num2;
        }
    }else{
        alert('please select a math');
    } 
}
```

Comment: you are getting an element by id. No element with id 'add' exists. Thus the null error. You have given a name 'add' though.

Comment: Wording - change "Select a math" to "Select an operation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to cast  Number on each input calculations
- Radio Button needs a consistent name to work as a group
- Your output to the p result is then set after the calculation

```js
function calculate() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
  var res;


  if (document.getElementById('add').checked) {
    res = num1 + num2;
  } else if (document.getElementById('sub').checked) {
    res = num1 - num2;
  } else if (document.getElementById('multi').checked) {
    res = num1 * num2;
  } else if (document.getElementById('divis').checked) {
    if (num2 == 0) {
      alert('Can not divide by ZERO!!');
    } else {
      res = num1 / num2;
    }
  } else {
    alert('please select an operation');
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res

}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter two numbers, select a math, click the button to see result.
  <br/>Enter first number:
  <input type='number' id='num1'>
  <br/>Enter second number:
  <input type='number' id='num2'>
  <br/>
  <h5>Select a math</h5>

  <input type='radio' name='operation' id='add'>Add
  <br>
  <input type='radio' name='operation' id='sub'>Subtract
  <br>
  <input type='radio' name='operation' id='multi'>Multiply
  <br>
  <input type='radio' name='operation' id='divis'>Division
  <br>

  <br>
  <button type='button' onclick='calculate();'>Calculate</button>
</form>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: would it be sufficient to use parseint() on the variable declarations to prevent having to retype number() multiple times

Comment: Yes that would be fine. I will adjust my answer

Comment: I had it incorrect the script is now working as expected

Answer (score 0):

For the buttons to be mutually exclusive they need to all have the same name.

```
<input type='radio' name='operation' id='add'>Add<br>
<input type='radio' name='operation' id='sub'>Subtract<br>
<input type='radio' name='operation' id='multi'>Multiply<br>
<input type='radio' name='operation' id='divis'>Division<br>
```

You are getting the error because you are using `getElementById` but you have no ID set. Change your current `name` attribute to `id` and your existing code should work.

Answer (score 0):

"ID" and "name" are not the same element in HTML.

Try modifying to something like:

id='add'

where your currently have

name='add'

Answer (score 0):

Giving several names means several radio inputs, which explains why several can be checked.
You get a null error for your getElementById because, in fact, no element with such an id exists.

Try

`<input type="radio" name="math" id="add">`

( changing the other radio elements accordingly ) instead and see whether that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Not Adding the `ids` can be handled using `name` also but you need `to have same name to allow only one selection`.A messy code using the `getElementsByName`.

```html
<form>
        Enter two numbers, select a math, click the button to see result.
        Enter first number: <input type='number' id='num1'>
        Enter second number: <input type='number' id='num2'>    
        <h5>Select a math</h5>
        <input type='radio' name='radio'>Add<br>
        <input type='radio' name='radio'>Subtract<br>
        <input type='radio' name='radio'>Multiply<br>
        <input type='radio' name='radio'>Division<br>
        <br>
        <button type='button' onclick='calculate();'>Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <p id='result'></p>

<script>
function calculate(){
    var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    var radio = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    var res="N/A";
    var selected=true;
    for(x in radio){      
    if(radio[x].checked && radio[x].nextSibling.data =='Add'){
        res = num1 + num2;
        selected=true
        break;
    }else if(radio[x].checked && radio[x].nextSibling.data=='Subtract'){
        res = num1 - num2;
        selected=true
        break;
    }else if(radio[x].checked && radio[x].nextSibling.data == 'Multiply'){
        res = num1 * num2;
        selected=true
        break;
    }else if(radio[x].checked && radio[x].nextSibling.data == 'Division'){
        if(num2 == 0){
            alert('Can not divide by ZERO!!');
        }else{
            res = num1 / num2;
            
        }
        selected=true
        break;
    }else{
        selected=false;
    }
 
}

    if(!selected){

            alert('please select a math');
        }

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=res;
}

</script>
```